# updating adapter in ListView android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have a problem with my adapter while trying to update my listView in Android. I've gone through similar questions here on stack but still didn't figure it out.

I am working on a sort of Bucket List App, and I start a new activity in order to add wish to a list of wishes. It's just a prototype for study purpose, and I try to make it without the asynchronous solution, just by using the adapter.add("user inserted wish"), but the app simply crashes, or it doesn't even start. I mention that I've checked the functionality of the activity that sends the message (I've simply displayed it as you can see on **onActivityResult**). Also the sample code provided below works, because I've commented the problem code, but doesn't add anything to the listView.

**So why I've assumed it doesn't work (if I use the commented code): if I keep my adapter declared inside *onCreate* it's not visible down in *onActivityResult* and I am not able to use the method add there, and also the adapter, and if i declare my adapter outside it simply crashes/doesn't start the app.**

```
package com.example.packagename.reforgedbucketlist;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.beatriceghetel.reforgedbucketlist.R.styleable.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String logMsg = "State";

    String[] wishesArray = {"Preset wish: use this app!","Preset wish: enjoy this app!","Preset wish: rate this app!","Preset wish: recommend this app!"};

    /*ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.activity_listview, wishesArray);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wishes_list);*/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.activity_listview, wishesArray);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wishes_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d(logMsg, "The onCreate() event");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);

        MenuItem item1 = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.about_id);
        MenuItem item2 = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.settings_id);
        MenuItem item3 = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.add_wish_id);



        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(logMsg, "The onStart() event");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(logMsg, "The onResume() event");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(logMsg, "The onPause() event");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(logMsg, "The onStop() event");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(logMsg, "The onDestroy() event");
    }

    public void onAddWishClick(MenuItem item) {
        Intent getNewWishIntent = new Intent(this, AddWishActivity.class);
        final int result = 1;
        getNewWishIntent.putExtra("CallingActivity", "Wish");
        startActivityForResult(getNewWishIntent, result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        TextView userWishView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_sent_back);
        String wishSentBack = data.getStringExtra("UserWish");
        userWishView.append(" " + wishSentBack);

        //adapter.add(wishSentBack);
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an Array which has a fixed size.

Try to change the declaration to this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String logMsg = "State";
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] wishesArray = {"Preset wish: use this app!","Preset wish: enjoy this app!","Preset wish: rate this app!","Preset wish: recommend this app!"};


// On create ....{
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(wishesArray ));

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.activity_listview, list);
//.... do the rest normally
}
```

And when you need to update your data:

```
    list.add(wishSentBack);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Modified, but still wasn't able to use `adapter.notifyDataChanged();` in _onActivityResult_ so I left that commented... result:  **Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.** Also Android Studio died... I'll retry right after it reopens

Comment: I had to restart the pc, the problem was with my emulator. Solved the problem with the adapter also, I've declared the list and adapter outside _onCreate_ method `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter adapter;` and used them inside that method like you've said. Now it works perfectly. Thank you!